# Circular definition in React's render method when using react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

What is `props.children` in React?

What defines these children?

Are they defined in a component's render method? I assume yes.

Are children always rendered? If yes, then why do I need to manually put `{this.props.children}` into the render method when using react-router? How does that make any sense ?

This is what I mean :

```
// modules/App.js
// ...
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>React Router Tutorial</h1>
        <ul role="nav">
          <li><Link to="/about">About</Link></li>
          <li><Link to="/repos">Repos</Link></li>
        </ul>

        {/* add this */}
        {this.props.children}

      </div>
    )
  }
// ...
```

Taken from [this](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial/tree/master/lessons/04-nested-routes) tutorial.

How does this not blow up due to **circular definition**?

Render method defines what is in `props.children` but render method itself contains `props.children` .

Why is this not a problem ?

Why is it needed to make this circular definition in the first place ?

I am confused.

EDIT:

`index.js`:

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import App from './modules/App'
import { Router, Route, hashHistory } from 'react-router'


// insert into index.js
import About from './modules/About'
import Repos from './modules/Repos'

// index.js
// ...
render((
    <Router history={hashHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={App}>
            {/* make them children of `App` */}
            <Route path="/repos" component={Repos}/>
            <Route path="/about" component={About}/>

        </Route>

    </Router>
), document.getElementById('app'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clue to this answer is that `children` lives under the `props` of the component. Basically, `this.props.children` is nothing more than a property of the component. Granted it is a somewhat special `prop` and an opaque data structure, but it is a `prop` nonetheless.

What this means is that `render` does *not* define what `this.props.children` is. Like any other `prop`, `children` is passed down from a parent component to a child. There is nothing fantastically special about `this.props.children` except it acts as a handy, built-in way to pass arbitrary inner elements from parent to child.

Passing `children` to a component like this:

```
<MyComponent>
    <div>Hello</div>
    <div>World</div>
</MyComponent>
```

Is not so different than doing it like this (and in fact you CAN do it like this, but it would be silly to do so because you end up bypassing some important React housekeeping):

```
<MyComponent children={[<div>Hello</div>, <div>World</div>]} />
```

So, there is no circular logic here. Components receive their `children` from their direct parent as a `prop`. The only thing that `render` does is define *how a component is rendered*. `render` is the presentational part of the component and is intentionally disconnected from the data model. If you did not put `{this.props.children}` into the `render` method, then the children simply wouldn't be displayed.

Since `children` are much like any other component `prop`, and they are represented as an array, you can do convenient stuff like using `Array.map` to modify or wrap each child in some way:

```
render() {
    <div>{this.props.children.map(function(ea){return <strong>{ea}</strong>})}</div>
}
```

I hope that clears it up for you.

Comment: Many thanks for the detailed answer JCD ! I think this cleared up a lot of confusion in my mind.

Comment: So basically `children` are only rendered if they are explicitly referred to in the render function ? If not then the value of children does not at all affect what appears on the screen ?

Comment: @jhegedus Yes. `this.props.children` is just data... it has no intrinsic value to the component that receives it and you can think of it just like any other `prop` that is passed from parent to child.